# Add a condition for "empty" string in Python

Tags: python, bash, beautifulsoup

In my Cyber and Information Security course I was given a project to build a tool which extracts IP ranges from a table that is located on a website.
The website also tells us who is the owner of these IP ranges and if there is no owner, the tool use the `whois` bash command with `grep` to fill the empty owner spots. The results I write to a file. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from os import popen
import bs4 as bs
import urllib
columnsCounter = 0
previousIp = ""
def ipCheck(currentIp):
    try:
        ipSplit = currentIp.split(".")
        if 1 <= len(ipSplit[0]) <= 3 and 1 <= len(ipSplit[1]) <= 3 and 1 <= len(ipSplit[2]) <= 3 and 1 <= len(ipSplit[3]) <= 3:
            result = ".".join(ipSplit)
            return result
        else:
            return
    except:
        return
web = urllib.urlopen('http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/al.html').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(web,'lxml')
someData = soup.find_all("table", {"border":"1","cellpadding":"6","bordercolor":"#000000"})
itemsList = someData[0].contents[2:]
f = open("ip.db", "w")
f.write("From IP\t\tTo IP\t\tNum IPs\tAssign Date\tOwner\n")
f.close()
f = open("ip.db", "a")
for item in itemsList:
    row = item.text[1:].split(" ")
    for column in row:
        column = column.encode("UTF-8")
        columnsCounter += 1
        isIp = ipCheck(column)
        if columnsCounter >= 5 and not isIp:
            f.write(column + " ")
        elif columnsCounter == 6 and isIp:
            cmd = "whois {} | grep desc | tail -n 1".format(previousIp)
            owner = popen(cmd).read().encode("UTF-8")
            owner = "{}\n".format(owner[16:-1])
            f.write(owner)
            columnsCounter = 1
        elif columnsCounter > 5 and isIp is not None:
            f.write("\n")
            columnsCounter = 1
        if columnsCounter <= 4:
            f.write(column + "\t")
            if columnsCounter == 1:
                previousIp = column
f.close()
```

The output file looks like that:

```
> From IP       To IP           Num IPs Assign Date Owner
> 31.22.48.0    31.22.63.255    4096    25/03/11    Albanian Mobile Communications SH.A. 
> 31.44.64.0    31.44.79.255    4096    24/02/11    Abissnet sh.a. 
> 46.99.0.0     46.99.255.255   65536   08/06/10      IPKO-469900/22
> 46.252.32.0   46.252.47.255   4096    17/12/10    4ALB shpk 
> 77.242.16.0   77.242.31.255   4096    22/02/07    Abissnet sh.a. 
> 79.106.0.0    79.106.255.255  65536   23/11/07    Albtelecom Sh.a. 
> 80.78.64.0    80.78.79.255    4096    04/07/01    ABCOM Shpk 
> 80.80.160.0   80.80.175.255   4096    17/07/01      IPKO-8080160
> 80.90.80.0    80.90.95.255    4096    03/06/05    ADA Holding - ADA AIR sh.p.k. 
> 80.91.112.0   80.91.127.255   4096    09/06/05    Abissnet sh.a. 
> 82.114.64.0   82.114.95.255   8192    22/12/03      Kujtesa Network
> 84.20.64.0    84.20.95.255    8192    02/09/04    Pronet sh.p.k. 
> 91.187.96.0   91.187.127.255  8192    24/11/06      IPKO-9118796
> 92.60.16.0    92.60.31.255    4096    30/11/07    Abissnet sh.a. 
> 95.107.128.0  95.107.255.255  32768   02/12/08    "Albanian Satellite Communications" sh.p.k. 
> 109.104.128.0 109.104.159.255 8192    04/09/09    ITirana Sh.p.k. 
> 109.236.32.0  109.236.47.255  4096    30/11/09    Abissnet sh.a. 
> 134.0.32.0    134.0.63.255    8192    01/11/11    Agjencia Kombetare Shoqerise se Informacionit 
> 213.207.32.0  213.207.63.255  8192    22/12/05    VIVO Communications Sh p k 
> 217.21.144.0  217.21.159.255  4096    21/10/10    Nisatel LTD 
> 217.24.240.0  217.24.255.255  4096    14/05/03    Albtelecom Sh.a. 
> 217.73.128.0  217.73.143.255  4096    17/01/11    ABCOM Shpk
```

THE PROBLEM IS: Under the `Owner` column there are a few "owners" who have a couple of spaces at the beginning of the owner name. These owner names were specifically filled up by the `whois` bash command. I found out that these spaces were added by the following python lines:

```
    if columnsCounter >= 5 and not isIp:
        f.write(column + " ")
```

From investigations I found out that it happens when the var `column` is equal to one of the blanked owners on the website. If I run `print column` I get  (2x spacebars) whose length is 2.

MY QUESTION IS: I don't want to filter by length (who knows, maybe there is an owner name that contains only 2 chars). Additionally, a condition of `if column == "  ":` (or any variation of that string) is not working. So how do I find out what is that string EXACTLY and FILTER it?

Comment: If the string of two spaces isn't filtering it, is it possible it's not two spacebar presses? It may be a different ASCII or unicode char perhaps. I suggest `print [ord(c) for c in column]` instead of `print column` to be sure the characters match `ord(' ')`.

Comment: If it is indeed whitespace, you can get rid of it by changing that line to `f.write(column.strip() + " ")`.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Thanks a lot man! I didn't know before about that "ord" function. Now I'm reading about it and I already found that these "2 spaces" are actually extended ASCII chars.

Comment: Cool, I'll add it as an answer with a suggestion to fix then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, if your filtering isn't matching, it's probable they aren't actually standard spacebar presses. The python function `ord(ch)` for some character `ch` will give a numeric representation of the character so you can disambiguate it from other similar looking characters.

Of course, you could just filter *that* character out when you discover what it is. But another method, which maybe would be better, would be to "sanitize" your strings---remove everything that's not alphabetical or alphanumeric or something, and your whitespaces would be removed, allowing you to actually filter an empty string.

For example, you can sanitize a column that has some unexpected characters in it; in this case, the string contains a digit, some non-English characters, and a symbol in the extended ASCII table thats not alphanumeric. If we wanted to keep everything except that symbol, something like this would do:

```
>>> column = "5ome çharß ¼"
>>> "".join([c for c in column if c.isalpha() or c.isdigit() or c == ' '])
'5ome çharß '
```

It kept the digits, alpha characters, even non-English ones, and spaces, but not the `¼` symbol. You could check if this sanitized string was equal to the empty string. I think this solution is nice because it generalizes relatively well.

If you're worried that there still might be spaces, you can `.strip()` the string which by default will strip it by spaces, and if that's the only thing in there, it'll give you an empty string. There's also a `'some string'.isspace()` method which checks if the string contains only whitespaces. Possibly you could even use this on your original weird column name; but I'm not sure if your character would be included as whitespace in this function or not as I don't know what the character is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the new information you gave on the comments did 90% of the job and I got to the next solution which works great: `        elif columnsCounter >= 5 and not isIp:
            for char in column:
                if 128 <= ord(char) <= 254:
                    exCharFlag = 11
                    continue
                else:
                    break
            if exCharFlag == 0:
                f.write(column + " ")
            else:
                exCharFlag = 0
                pass`   **Side note: I don't know how to post my code on comments...

Comment: @GadiTabak Excellent! Glad you got a working solution. There are a ton of ways to complete this task. If my answer/comments answered your question could you mark it as accepted? Also, for inline code, use backticks: \`some_code\` produces `some_code` just like in the edited version of your original post. :)